# Manterner barra de herramientas de TinyMCE al perder el focus

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, tinymce, focus

Estoy usando TinyMCE 6 con React y estoy creando un plugin para agregar comentarios con la selección del texto dentro del tiny y el texto del comentario lo agrego desde otro componente externo, pero a la hora de hacer clic en el input del componente externo para escribir se pierde el focus de tiny por lo que se oculta la barra y esa selección que tengo de la parte del texto dentro de tiny.

Ya trate mantener la referencia de tiny y volverle a asignar el focus, pero el cursor lo posiciona dentro de tinymce y no puedo escribir en el input externo.

¿Hay alguna manera para que pueda mantener la barra de herramientas o "focus" de tinymce mientras escribo en un input externo?